# How to create multiple virtual machines in azure using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

I tried with the following playbook and its not working. Not sure what I am missing here.

```
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - vars/azure.yml
  tasks:
    - name: create VM
      azure:
        name: '{{ vm_name }}'
        role_size: '{{ role_size }}'
        image: '{{ image_name }}'
        location: '{{ location }}'
        user: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        subscription_id: '{{ subscription_id }}'
        management_cert_path: '{{ certificate_path }}'
        storage_account: '{{ storage_account_name }}'
        virtual_network_name: '{{ virtual_network_name }}'
        wait: yes
      with_items: 
        - { name: "{{ vm_names_list }}" } 
      register : azure

    - name  : Debug Azure output
      debug :
        var : azure
```

I have mentioned my `vm_names_list` like this :

```
vm_names_list:
    - "loferVM123"
    - "loferVM234"
```

It does not do what I expect. I expected it to create three VMs. But it creates only one VM. In the debug output it gives me the items in the list but only creates one VM.

This is the debug output:

```
"virtual_network_name": "myVirtualNetwork"
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": "",
                    "module_name": "azure"
                },
                "item": {
                    "vm_name": [
                        "loferVM123",
                        "loferVM234"
                    ]
                },
                "public_dns_name": "lofervm175.cloudapp.net"
```

My variable file:

```
subscription_id: "ID"
certificate_path: "/path/to/certs/mycert.pem"
image_name: "5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-67-20150815"
storage_account_name: "mystorageacc"
virtual_network_name: "myVirtualNetwork"
username: "user"
password: "password"
vm_name: "lophani"
vm_names_list:
    - "loferVM123"
    - "loferVM234"
role_size: "Small"
location: "Central US"
data_disk_size: "100"
commitlog_disk_size: "10"
```

This is the output from azure-cli vm show

```
data:    DNSName "lofervm234.cloudapp.net"
data:    Location "Central US"
data:    VMName "loferVM234"
data:    IPAddress "10.0.2.6"
data:    InstanceStatus "ReadyRole"
data:    InstanceSize "Small"
data:    Image "5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-67-20150815"
data:    OSDisk hostCaching "ReadWrite"
data:    OSDisk name "loferVM234-loferVM234-0-201510262116050841"
data:    OSDisk mediaLink "http://portalvhdskswbj32fl5cx8.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/loferVM234-loferVM234-2015-10-26.vhd"
data:    OSDisk sourceImageName "5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-67-20150815"
data:    OSDisk operatingSystem "Linux"
data:    OSDisk iOType "Standard"
data:    DataDisks 0 hostCaching "None"
data:    DataDisks 0 label "loferVM234-loferVM234-loferVM234-0"
data:    DataDisks 0 name "loferVM234-loferVM234-0-201510262116380749"
data:    DataDisks 0 logicalDiskSizeInGB 100
data:    DataDisks 0 mediaLink "https://portalvhdskswbj32fl5cx8.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/loferVM234-b73613825dfb0bcb.vhd"
data:    DataDisks 0 iOType "Standard"
data:    DataDisks 1 hostCaching "None"
data:    DataDisks 1 label "loferVM234-loferVM234-loferVM234-1"
data:    DataDisks 1 name "loferVM234-loferVM234-1-201510262117180308"
data:    DataDisks 1 logicalUnitNumber 1
data:    DataDisks 1 logicalDiskSizeInGB 100
data:    DataDisks 1 mediaLink "https://portalvhdskswbj32fl5cx8.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/loferVM234-cf18946abcbfe4c8.vhd"
data:    DataDisks 1 iOType "Standard"
data:    ReservedIPName ""
data:    VirtualIPAddresses 0 address "104.43.202.234"
data:    VirtualIPAddresses 0 name "loferVM234ContractContract"
data:    VirtualIPAddresses 0 isDnsProgrammed true
data:    Network Endpoints 0 localPort 22
data:    Network Endpoints 0 name "TCP-22"
data:    Network Endpoints 0 port 22
data:    Network Endpoints 0 protocol "tcp"
data:    Network Endpoints 0 virtualIPAddress "104.43.202.234"
data:    Network Endpoints 0 enableDirectServerReturn false
data:    Network Endpoints 0 idleTimeoutInMinutes 4
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it isn't working? Is there some error output? Does it silently do nothing? Does it do something but not what you expected? If so, what things does it do and what were you expecting?

Comment: Can you also include a (sanitised!) version of your azure.yml vars file too?

Comment: Also, what does the instance look like in Azure? Either via the Azure web UI or the output of `azure vm list` in the Azure CLI client and then `azure vm show $instance_name`